# Why is IPython displaying multiple characters?

Tags: windows, ipython

I have just installed IPython for Windows but this keeps on happening:

```py
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: i = 11

In [2]: iiii
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: iiiiii
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: iiiiiiii
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: Press ENTER to continue...                                                                                                                                                                          
Unhandled exception in event loop:
  File "c:\users\<username>\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 768, in _loop_self_reading
    f.result()  # may raise
  File "c:\users\<username>\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 808, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "c:\users\<username>\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 457, in finish_recv
    raise ConnectionResetError(*exc.args)

Exception [WinError 995] The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
Press ENTER to continue...
```

For `In [2]`, `In [3]` and `In [4]`, I pressed `i` only once. Their length also increased after I pressed ENTER. 
The error happens at random times but the effects are purely graphical as otherwise it works fine.
Additionaly, this happens when I press backspace:

```py
In [1]: a = "bc|cb" = a
```

(Backspace was pressed after `|`)

I have re-installed Python and this happend again.
I installed IPython using pip, using the instructions on the IPython website for Windows

To make matters even more confusing, my python shell has the ipython autocomplete installed. 
But if I press tab when nothing can autocomplete this happens:

```py
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> Readline internal error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\console.py", line 768, in hook_wrapper_23
    res = ensure_str(readline_hook(prompt))
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 571, in readline
    self._readline_from_keyboard()
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 536, in _readline_from_keyboard
    if self._readline_from_keyboard_poll():
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 556, in _readline_from_keyboard_poll
    result = self.mode.process_keyevent(event.keyinfo)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\emacs.py", line 243, in process_keyevent
    r = self.process_keyevent_queue[-1](keyinfo)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\emacs.py", line 286, in _process_keyevent
    r = dispatch_func(keyinfo)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\basemode.py", line 257, in complete
    completions = self._get_completions()
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\basemode.py", line 200, in _get_completions
    r = self.completer(ensure_unicode(text), i)
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\rlcompleter.py", line 80, in complete
    readline.redisplay()
AttributeError: module 'readline' has no attribute 'redisplay'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with ipython 7.19.0 and Python 3.9.0 in both PowerShell (5.1.18362.1171) and the Command Prompt. It's also strange, when I press delete the last character entered appears on the command line. I am still searching for explanations and a fix, in the meantime I use Jupyter QtConsole which works fine

```
jupyter qtconsole
```